# Conditional Truncation of a URL with REGEX

Tags: regex, splunk

I'm establishing a list of base URL's distilled from Splunk data. The definition of a "base url" is to ignore any parameters and then truncate so that everything to the left of the last slash remains.

Unfortunately, not all URL's contain parameters and I'm stuck on how to incorporate a conditional part in the regex. This is what I have so far:

```
| makeresults<br>
| eval url="www.google.com/search?q=best+something&rlz=1C1GCEA_enNL789NL790&oq=best+something&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4104j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"<br>
| rex field=url "^(?<url1>[^\?]*)\?.*$"<br>
| rex field=url1 "^(?<base_url>.*)\/.*$"
```

So this works perfectly for a URL containing parameters, the above gives "www.google.com" for the base_url. But if I remove the parameters, it returns nothing - e.g. `base_url=""`. So I need to check first if the URL contains a question mark, if so, remove everything to the right, if not, don't do anything. I've been trying things to no avail so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for anyone interested, the solution was quite a small modification to the original code:

```
    | makeresults
    | eval url="www.google.com/search?q=best+something"
    | rex field=url "^(?<url1>[^\?]*)|\?.*$"<br>
    | rex field=url1 "^(?<base_url>.*)\/.*$"
```

It's the "|" following the closing parenthesis in the first "rex field" line. This will first strip off everything after the question mark and then strip off everything after the last slash.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regex:

`^(?:https?:\/\/)?(\S*?)[\?\/\n\r]`

I am handling the cases for the presence of http/https. Then capturing all the non-whitespace characters lazily until either of `/`, `?`, `\n`, or `\r` is encountered.

The only capture group contains the base URL as expected.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hBoJ2L/2)

Comment: Thanks for sharing! The only trouble is that if the url were: "www.google.com/somesubdir/anothersubdir/search?q=best+something&rlz=1C1GCEA_enNL789NL790&oq=best+something&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4104j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8", I would need the result to be: "www.google.com/somesubdir/anothersubdir" or "www.google.com/somesubdir/anothersubdir/" (don't care too much about the trailing slash).